# How to properly setup php_gmp on OSX with xampp

Tags: php, macos, xampp, osx-yosemite

I've installed XAMPP on osx 10.10 .

I need `php_gmp` so i tried to setup it using:

```
$ brew install php55 --with-gmp
```

Then, I activated the dependency by modifing php.ini

```
extension=gmp.so
```

Apache restarted does not work, so i tried to activate in php.ini:

```
extension=php_gmp.so
```

Resterting the server but nothing anyway

**PHP error Log**

```
[24-Mar-2016 08:00:26 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_gmp.so' - dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_gmp.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
[24-Mar-2016 08:00:26 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/gmp.so' - dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/gmp.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling it but using the code

```
brew install homebrew/php/php55-gmp
```